Identify specific set of values from data.table inbetween flags
I have a data table with a different number of entries per ID.
The third column contains flags. For each ID, I want to remove all entries from value column whenever a flag equals 1 until the next 1 occurs.
Example Code:
library(data.table)

set.seed(666)
toyDataset = data.table(ID = c(rep("A",6),
                               rep("B",8),
                               rep("C",7),
                               rep("D",10)),
                        value = runif(31),
                        flag = c(c(0,0,1,1,0,0),
                                 c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0),
                                 c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0),
                                 c(0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1)))

desiredResult = toyDataset
desiredResult$value[c(3:4,
                      7:11,
                      19:21,
                      24:26,29:31)] = NA

I have one apparently working solution based on various conditions, which looks kinda messy though:
switch = 0
for(i in 1:nrow(toyDataset)){
  
  #reset switch with new ID
  if(i > 1 && toyDataset$ID[i] != toyDataset$ID[(i-1)]) switch = 0 
  #conditions to toggle switch
  if(toyDataset$flag[i] == 1 && switch == 0){
    switch = 1 
    toyDataset$value[i] = NA
  } else if (toyDataset$flag[i] == 1 && switch == 1){
    switch = 0
    toyDataset$value[i] = NA
  }
  if(switch == 1) toyDataset$value[i] = NA
}

I was hoping there was a more efficient solution, perhaps making use of data.table.
Help is much appreciated!

Abstracting away the processing of the flags will (imo) make it easier to reduce the mess:
between_flag <- function(x) cumsum(x) %% 2 == 1 | x

toyDataset[toyDataset[, between_flag(flag), ID]$V1,
           value := NA]


Thank you! This really does look much better. One question though: What exactly does the " | x " part do? I've only ever seen the " | " operator used as "OR" but apparently it does not equal " cumsum(x) %% 2 == 1 OR cumsum(x) %%2 == x" . At a closer look I think it converts 1 to TRUE and 0 to FALSE?

Should probably be ... | as.logical(x) to make things clearer. It make the logic work for the closing of the gap occurs.
